# Can't create a Laravel Passport token in feature test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-passport

Since upgrading my application from Laravel 7 to 8, I've been having some minor issues with Laravel Passport. I created a test feature to retrieve a Passport token to make sure it was working, but I can't get it back. When I call `passport.token` I always get the same message:

```
array:3 [
  "error" => "invalid_client"
  "error_description" => "Client authentication failed"
  "message" => "Client authentication failed"
]
```

I have tried several things, but here is my current code:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Passport\Client as OauthClient;
use Modules\Sapiendo\Tests\SapiendoTestCase;

/** @test */
    public function we_can_authenticate_and_use_api_endpoints_with_client_credential_grant_token()
    {
        $customer = $this->createFullCustomer();

        /** @var OauthClient $oauthClient */
        $oauthClient = OauthClient::create([
            'user_id' => null,
            'name' => 'ClientCredentials Grant Client',
            'secret' => Str::random(40),
            'redirect' => 'http://localhost',
            'personal_access_client' => false,
            'password_client' => false,
            'revoked' => false,
        ]);
        $state = Str::random(40);
        $autorization = $this->get(route('passport.authorizations.authorize', [
            'client_id' => $oauthClient->id,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => '',
            'state' => $state,
        ]));
        $autorization->assertStatus(302);
        // D'abord on demande un token avec les identifiants créés
        $tokenRequest = $this->post(route('passport.token'), [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $oauthClient->getKey(),
            'client_secret' => $oauthClient->secret,
            'code' => $state,
        ]);
            //->assertSuccessful();
        dd($tokenRequest->json());
    ...
```

Before this update I didn't have to go through the `passport.authorizations.authorize` route to get the code, I could go directly to the `passport.token` step

Answer (score 0):

Since Passport 9.0, the client ID and secret are hashed. There is a function to retrieve this non-hashed secret from the Passport client object

```php
$oauthClient = OauthClient::create([
            'user_id' => null,
            'name' => 'ClientCredentials Grant Client',
            'secret' => Str::random(40),
            'redirect' => 'http://localhost',
            'personal_access_client' => false,
            'password_client' => false,
            'revoked' => false,
        ]);
 $tokenRequest = $this->post(route('passport.token'), [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $oauthClient->id,
            'client_secret' => $oauthClient->getPlainSecretAttribute(),
            'code' => $state,
        ]);
```